# Guessing a solution to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

"A first order differential equation is given by $$x'(t)+5x(t)=e^{-t}cos(2t), t \in \mathbb{R}$$

**Show that the differential equation has a solution on the form** $$x(t)=ae^{-t}cos(2t)+be^{-t}, t \in \mathbb{R}$$

**and determine the complete solution to the differential equation**

Could someone explain the correct way to proceed? I don't seem to understand how this "Guessing a solution" works and how it can lead to the complete solution

Comment: Why do you try to guess the solution? It is just  a first order linear equation and there is an algorithm for it.

Comment: Its a requirement - Sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: Also according to the given equation there must be $e^{4t}$ exponential term in the solution.

Comment: You don't have to guess, the guess has been made for you. You're just asked to show it's a good guess. Probably, how to make the guess in the first place will be a future topic in your studies.

Comment: your solution is not correct

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$y_h=Ce^{-5t}$$ and for the particular solution make the ansatz $$y_P=Ae^{-t}(B\cos(2t)+C\sin(2t))$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a general formula to solve this equation and can be found in any textbook. In your case, just consider the homogeneous equation
$$
x'_0(t)+5x_0(t)=0.
$$
The solution is $x_0(t)=Ce^{-5t}$, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. Now, for your equation just choose the solution
$$
   x(t)=x_0(t)y(t)=e^{-5t}y(t)
$$
where, in place of the constant $C$, now I have an unknown function to be computed. This can be done by substituting it in the full equation, that is
$$
   x'(t)+5x(t)=y'(t)e^{-5t}=e^{-t}\cos(2t)
$$
and you are left with the evaluation of the known integral
$$
   y(t)=b+\int dt'e^{4t'}\cos(2t')
$$
yielding the general solution.